# Name of present user doesn't appear in autocomplete list

Tags: bug, chat

Even though Dharmendra is currently in the room and talking to me, the name "Dharmendra" doesn't appear in the autocomplete list; instead another user appears twice:

[image: screen shot of chat displaying the issue]

A few minutes later, now there's only one name. Dharmendra still nowhere in sight.

[image: another chat screenshot]

Comment: Yeah it is strange.

Comment: I can't reproduce this; I see Dharmendra in the autocomplete list. Does this issue persist when you refresh the chat room page?

Comment: This screenshot I had taken a few minutes ago while I 'm talking to him(Dharmendra). Me too able to see in the list as I talking with him about an hour(havn't check by refreshing) but in between this happened.

Comment: @hotveryspicy i suggest you to try [ctrl+f5] once.